# How to decode Html and escape characters in Textview android

Tags: android, html, textview

I have specific data that contain some html characters such as

```
   &lt; for < 
   &gt; for > 
   &amp; for &
```

And some escape characters like this `\r\n\r\n`, When i try to display my data in text-view using `tv.setText(str);` this only decode escape characters and show html characters as it.

And when i try to use something like this `Html.fromHtml(str)` not decode  the escape characters.

So, there is any way to handle this issue ?

Answer (score 6):

`Html.fromHtml(str).toString();` should work. I tell you the reason -

Your string is `Html`. Unicode characters are stored as encoded character entities. The `&#x`; notation is used to escape unicode characters for transmission over ISO-8859-1. **A web browser decodes them to display actual unicode characters.**

Decoding HTML is decoding HTML entities to Java raw unicode characters.

For example:

```
String html = "B &#x0026; This is HTML";
String java = Html.fromHtml(html);
#=> Output: "B \u0026 This is HTML"
String strJava = Html.fromHtml(html).toString();
#=> Output: "B & This is HTML"
```

Comment: You can filter out that using `str= str.replaceAll( "[\\u202C\\u202A]", "" );`

Comment: but i want to use it's value

Comment: To decode `unicodes` you may want to use `StringEscapeUtils` of http://www.mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6

Answer (score 4):

You have to use Html.fromHtml() method. This method returns displayable styled text from the provided HTML string.

Below API Level 23 (Before Nougat):

`textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<h2>Html String</h2>"));`

From API Level 23 (From nougat):

`textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<h2>Html String</h2>", Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT));`

Comment: i try it before but it ignore escape characters

Comment: @Azak It's working properly. Please give me a sample string which is not working.

Comment: you can try something like this

Comment: you can try something like this `D website \r\n\r\nThe D website also offers the  wide range of specialties &amp; services.`