# settext from getstring from jsonobject shows &#039; instead of '

Tags: java, android, json, encoding

It probably has to do with encoding or decoding but I'm very new in java/android and don't really know how to deal with this. Searches online doesn't show me helpfull todo's.

so my response.getString("key"); contains a ' which then outputs it as a &#0039 in my textview.
the source is a jsonobject

Any ideas?

Comment: `&#39;` is the HTML (XML) entity for the apostrophe. Apostrophe also is a special character in HTML and XML. There should be a final semi-colon `;` . Maybe that helps finding the cause.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to decode Html and escape characters in Textview android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42815470/how-to-decode-html-and-escape-characters-in-textview-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`textview.setText(Html.fromHtml("your_string").toString());` should work. I tell you the reason

Your string is HTML encoded. Unicode characters are stored as encoded character entities. The &#x; notation is used to escape unicode characters. A web browser decodes them. Decoding HTML is decoding HTML entities to Java raw unicode characters.

See more details/references:

- https://alvinalexander.com/android/how-show-html-string-in-android-textview-webview
- [How to decode Html and escape characters in Textview android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42815470/how-to-decode-html-and-escape-characters-in-textview-android/42816044#42816044)
- [How to decode Html and escape characters in Textview android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42815470/how-to-decode-html-and-escape-characters-in-textview-android)

Comment: Perfect answer. Works like a charm